# Can I make sure no pixels are drawn outside a specified rectangle in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create screen-in-screen functionality in my HTML5 game, and to do this I'm thinking the following pseudo-code:

```
//Called once per frame
function draw(){
  set a mask rectangle
  draw only pixels of current frame that are inside this rectangle
}
```

I know I can check the coordinates of individual pixels before drawing them but this seems like it will have a severe impact in performance and want to avoid it...

Is there a native way of implementing this using 2D context methods? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't check for single pixels, just draw whole elements which intersects with current view of your "smaller screen"

Some examples how can u achieve "screen-in-screen":

Create another (buffer) canvas representing your in-game screen, draw on it, and then draw it on the main canvas.

or

Create another Canvas element which will work as a layer, give it higher z-index than the main canvas, add it to current DOM tree and draw on it.

or

Use [clip](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/)

---

ps: benchmark for drawing outside current viewport: http://jsperf.com/comparing-onscreen-offscreen-rendering-to-canvas

Comment: The link you provided seems to have everything I need! I think I'll go with clip(). All I want to make sure is see what happens if the "going to be clipped" pixels are drawn on top of another sprite. Does it get redrawn? Does it get overwritten? I'll check it once I return home and accept there :)

Answer (score 0):

If it would be reasonable for the feature you have in mind to have a separate drawing element for the rectangle in question [`overflow: hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#x0) (CSS) would do it. The browser's layout engine would then be responsible for the clipping.

Comment: The only way I'm thinking of this to work, it to create new canvas elements and absolutely positioning them over the current main stage... What I want to do is have only one canvas element and work only with JS classes. Sounds like a good solution but unfortunately I don't think this will work in my case :(